# Prevent page URL pass into GTM

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

We have integrated Google tag manager in our web app and we are using customized data layer property. Also we have integrated Google Analytics tracking in GTM.

Whenever our page is loaded, in GTM get track of Page URL using built in variable of GTM "Page URL". And it gets this complete page URL into Google Analytics also.

We do not want to pass our complete Page URL to GTM and in Google analytics.

Is it possible to hide this Page URL and do not display anywhere in GTM and in Google Analytics?

Comment: For security reasons we do not want to pass on the encrypted querystring parameter to Google analytics i.e we only want to see the hits to the page in google analytics without passing the querysting parameters. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

if you dont wish to have "Page URL" in GTM ,you can uncheck the variable check box in GTM in below steps

1)Click on configure button under variables in GTM

[image]

2)Uncheck the "Page url" check box in configuration

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.We have tried this, then the URL is not showing in GTM, however its showing in Google analytics console. We also need to hide it from google analytics.

Comment: For security reasons we do not want to pass on the encrypted querystring parameter to Google analytics i.e we only want to see the hits to the page in google analytics without passing the querysting parameters. Is this even possible?